# What percent am I?

Tags: gene

*If my Great Great Great Great Grandma was one hundred percent Hispanic what percent am I? I'm unsure of what percentage in this ethnicity I would be.

Comment: You need to include information about all 64 of them before one can answer. If for example the other 63 are each 0%, it needs to be included in your question.

Comment: That depends on which genes are passed on with each generation, all we can assess from the given information is most likely average estimated percentage of your ancestors DNA you carry assuming no other sources, which would be 0.5 raised to the 6th power. however these assumptions are rarely true.

Answer (score 3):

**Interpretation of the question**

How do you define "being xth percent hispanic"? In a simple conversation, when people say that they are 25% hispanic (or any other etnic group of course), they just mean that they have one grand parent that was born in a clearly hispanic community/country and that all the others were born from completely unrelated etnical background.

**Answer**

You would be $\frac{1}{2^6} = \frac{1}{64}$ hispanic.

Comment: OP did not mention anything about the other 63, could be a trick question! :-)

Comment: @uhoh I think I made clear that I was making this assumption in my answer.

Comment: 25% could be one grandparent... or two great-grandparents, or four great-great-grandparents...

Comment: @Remi.b what's that `0.01`?

Comment: one percent as the OP indicated

Comment: one **hundred** percent.